# Python 'nan' when array is removed from data type object

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

I am working on a project where I want to read a binary STL file. I copied portions of someone's open source code and had no trouble.  However, now I need to manipulate this data, and when I pull the normal vector array out of the data type object which stores the triangle data, I am getting nans.

The data type object is structured as follows:

```
triangle_data = np.dtype([
    ('normals', np.float32, (3, )),
    ('v0', np.float32, (3, )),
    ('v1', np.float32, (3, )),
    ('v2', np.float32, (3, )),
    ('attr', 'u2', (1, )),
])
```

And the section which creates nans is here:

```
def identify_surfaces(self):
        tri_list = self.triangle_data
        #This print has the correct data, no nans!
        print(tri_list)
        for n in range(len(tri_list)):
            surface_list = []
            normal_vec = tri_list[n]['normals']
            #this print is filled with nans Q_Q
            print(normal_vec)
```

I suspect this has something to do with the float32 data type in the data type object, but I am not sure how to resolve this.  It is not acceptable to dismiss data with nans in it, and the nan data could either be 0, 1 or -1.

Thanks for any insight!

Here is the output of print(tri_list)

```
[([-1.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01], [ 0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, -1.0000000e+00], [ 0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.5240001e+02,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([ 0.0000000e+00, -1.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.5240001e+02,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.5240001e+02,  0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01], [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([-0.0000000e+00, -1.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.5240001e+02,  0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01], [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01], [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([ 1.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, -0.0000000e+00], [ 1.5240001e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.5240001e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.5240001e+02,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([ 1.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.5240001e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.5240001e+02,  0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.5240001e+02,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([-3.7314969e-32, -1.1194490e-31, -1.0000000e+00], [ 0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [ 5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01, -1.8956003e-30], [ 1.5240001e+02,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, -1.0000000e+00], [ 1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.5240001e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.5240001e+02,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([ 3.7314969e-32,  3.7314972e-32, -1.0000000e+00], [ 5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01, -1.8956003e-30], [ 1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.5240001e+02,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([-1.0000000e+00, -0.0000000e+00, -0.0000000e+00], [ 0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01], [0])
([ 0.0000000e+00, -0.0000000e+00,  1.0000000e+00], [ 1.5240001e+02,  0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.5240001e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01], [0])
([ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  1.0000000e+00], [ 1.5240001e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01], [0])
([ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  1.0000000e+00], [ 5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01], [0])
([ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  1.0000000e+00], [ 1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01], [0])
([-1.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [ 5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 5.0799999e+01,  1.0160000e+02,  0.0000000e+00], [ 5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01, -1.8956003e-30], [0])
([ 0.0000000e+00,  1.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [ 0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01, -1.8956003e-30], [ 0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([-0.0000000e+00,  1.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [ 0.0000000e+00,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01, -1.8956003e-30], [0])
([ 3.7314969e-32,  0.0000000e+00, -1.0000000e+00], [ 1.0160000e+02,  1.0160000e+02,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [ 5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01, -1.8956003e-30], [0])
([ 0.0000000e+00,  3.7314969e-32, -1.0000000e+00], [ 5.0799999e+01,  1.0160000e+02,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.0160000e+02,  1.0160000e+02,  0.0000000e+00], [ 5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01, -1.8956003e-30], [0])
([ 0.0000000e+00,  1.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.5240001e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([ 1.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, -0.0000000e+00], [ 1.0160000e+02,  1.0160000e+02,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.0160000e+02,  1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([ 1.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.0160000e+02,  1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([-0.0000000e+00,  1.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [ 1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.5240001e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.5240001e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  1.0000000e+00], [ 1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [ 5.0799999e+01,  1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01], [ 5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [0])
([-1.0000000e+00, -0.0000000e+00, -0.0000000e+00], [ 5.0799999e+01,  1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01], [ 5.0799999e+01,  1.0160000e+02,  0.0000000e+00], [ 5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [0])
([ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  1.0000000e+00], [ 1.0160000e+02,  1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01], [ 5.0799999e+01,  1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01], [0])
([ 0.0000000e+00,  1.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [ 5.0799999e+01,  1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.0160000e+02,  1.0160000e+02,  0.0000000e+00], [ 5.0799999e+01,  1.0160000e+02,  0.0000000e+00], [0])
([-0.0000000e+00,  1.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00], [ 5.0799999e+01,  1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.0160000e+02,  1.0160000e+02,  5.0799999e+01], [ 1.0160000e+02,  1.0160000e+02,  0.0000000e+00], [0])]
```

Here is the output of tri_list[n]:

```
tri_list[n]: ([-3.731497e-32, -1.119449e-31,           nan], [ 0. , 50.8,  0. ], [ 5.0799999e+01,  5.0799999e+01, -1.8956003e-30], [152.40001,   0.     ,   0.     ], [0])
```

Nans only appear in the triangle 'normal' vector data

Comment: no one can help you without a [mcve]

Comment: Can you provide the output of `print(tri_list)`?

Comment: `triangle_data` is a dictionary?

Comment: @Patol75 I provided the data for print(tri_list).  It is a structured array.  When I try to get just the information for a single triangle with tri_list[n] I start to see nans.

Comment: @DrBwts its a structured array which is constructed from unpacked binary data from an STL file made in solidworks.

Comment: Is it data nan? Or does it appear only in print? What do `numpy.isnan` and `numpy.isfinite` tell about values of array?

Comment: in the OP what if the value of `n` in `print(tri_list[n])`?